# KDE Plasma problems: All launchers broken, app launcher empty, desktop error message, all file associations missing

Tags: kde, gentoo, qt, plasma

After updating Qt to 5.15.8 (testing, `~amd64`) on my Gentoo system running KDE Plasma 5.26.5 (`~amd64`), I'm dealing with a bunch of issues with the desktop:

- All launchers are broken, appearing as blank files. If I click on any launcher, I get an toast notification from Plasma Workspace with the error "Unknown application folder".
- The desktop itself shows the following error message:

  > The file or folder $HOME/Desktop does not exist.
- The Application Launcher menu is completely empty.
- All file associations are missing. If I open Dolphin via KRunner (minimizing all windows and typing while on the desktop) and try to open any file, I get an empty list of applications, regardless of file type.

Rolling back the Qt update to 5.15.7 (stable, `amd64`) did not help. The desktop was running during the update, so something likely got corrupted during the update process.

I do have a Snapper snapshot of the system from eight days ago, so I'm wondering if there's there some specific configuration file that got corrupted which I could restore to recover from this condition. Otherwise, where does the problem lie? I really don't want to erase my whole Plasma configuration.

**Edit:** The same issues are visible on a completely new user account, so the issue is with KDE itself.

**Edit 2:** A rebuild of Qt and KDE packages did not help.

**Edit 3:** Reverting the system (but not `/home`) to the last snapshot fixed the desktop error message, but not the broken launchers. Deleting all `qmlcache` folders in `.cache` did not help.

**Edit 4:** The `dev-qt/*` and `kde*/*` packages are built with the LLVM/Clang 15 toolset.

Most of the issues are visible in the screenshot below.

[image: Broken KDE Plasma desktop]

Comment: 1/ "running KDE Plasma 5.26" You mean *unstable* 5.26.5 ? 2/ *after updating Qt* You mean from 5.15.7 to *unstable* 5.15.8 ?

Comment: Yes, edited the question to clarify.

Comment: Did you try wiping the .cache directory ? After whatever qt update I systematically delete all qmlcache entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exact same problem here on Gentoo, I also have everything compiled with clang (no LTO however).
For me this happend after the update to Qt to 5.15.8 as well, however I'm not sure if this problem manifested earlier and updating dev-qt invalidated the cache which made this issue visible.

This problem still persists with using `dev-qt/*-5.15.8-9999` versions from `qt` and `kde-frameworks-5-live`, `kde-gear-live` and `kde-plasma-live` sets from `kde` overlay.

Also cleaned all qt and kde configuration files found in `~/.config`, `~/.cache` and `~/.local/share/`.

I did file a bug here https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=464140, however I'm not sure if this is the right place, or if kservice is really the problem.

**Edit 1:** Forcing a rebuild with gcc of `dev-qt/*`, `kde-frameworks/*`, `kde-plasma/*` and `kde-apps` fixed the issue (at least for the git versions).

**Edit 2:** Rebuilt `~amd64` packages with gcc and it works as well, so the culprit seems to be clang-15.0.6

**Edit 3:** The same issue occurs when using `clang` with `-O2`. Aggressive compiler flags being the issue can be ruled out. However I could boil the problem down to `dev-qt/*`, compiling this category with `gcc` should be enough.

Comment: Thanks, I'll switch the `dev-qt/*` and `kde*/*` packages back to GCC and try again.

Comment: And looks like using GCC did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to roll back the system to the last snapshot (excluding `/home`, some configuration and log files, and kernels and modules), delete all the `.kcache` files and `qmlcache` folders in `~/.cache`, and bring the system up-to-date again.

I'm not sure what went wrong, but I suspect the KDE packages don't play nice with the latest Qt packages. While I haven't had issues with the testing (`~amd64`) KDE packages (and I have `kde*/* ~amd64` in `package.accept_keywords`), I'll be sticking with stable Qt for the time being (at least until the next KDE update).

**Edit:** I tried the Qt update again without the X server running and got the same problem. Ended up rolling it back

Comment: Having followed for >10 years the qt* & kde* packages stabilization requests under gentoo-bugzilla discouraged me very soon to run qt* & kde-plasma & kde-frameworks tildarched… :-) Anyway… Since qt*5* updates are provided by the KDE team and generally distributed before a kde-plasma & framework & apps release update, I would strongly advise **not** to run qt* stable and kde-plasma & framework tildarched.

Comment: Updated my answer. FWIW I have Qt and KDE packages built with Clang, the latter with full LTO.